# Append to the numpy array another numpy array as array, not it's elements

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I want to to make an array of arrays, but when I use `np.append` I get the list if their elements:

```
import numpy as np
im_data = np.array(['image0','image1','image2','image3','image4','image5','image6','image7','image8','image9','image10','image11','image12','image13','image14'])
batches = [[1,2,3,4],[7,8,9,10],[3,4,5,6]]

image_batches = []
for batch in batches:
    image_batches = np.append(image_batches,[im_data[batch]])
```

This is what I get:

> In: image_batches
>
> Out:  `array(['image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4', 'image7',  'image8', 'image9', 'image10', 'image3', 'image4', 'image5', 'image6'], dtype='<U32')`

and this is what I need:

> `array([['image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4'], ['image7', 'image8', 'image9', 'image10'], ['image3', 'image4', 'image5', 'image6']], dtype='<U7')`

I achieved this by using

```
image_batches = im_data[batches[0]]
for batch in batches[1:]:
    image_batches = np.vstack([image_batches, im_data[batch]])
```

but maybe there is more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Can't you make one list with all those `im_data[batch]`.  Repeated `np.append` or `vstack` in a loop is inefficient.  Do one `vstack` on a list.  You already know how to make an array from a list of items (or list of lists).

Comment: Does `im_data[batches]` do anything useful?  If you can index with a sublist, I think you can do the same with the whole list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like mentioned by @hpaulj in comments, you can directly use advances indexing:

```
im_data[np.array(batches)]
```

output:

```
[['image1' 'image2' 'image3' 'image4']
 ['image7' 'image8' 'image9' 'image10']
 ['image3' 'image4' 'image5' 'image6']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list comprehension` and then convert it into `numpy.array`:

```
import numpy as np
im_data = np.array(['image0','image1','image2','image3','image4','image5','image6','image7','image8','image9','image10','image11','image12','image13','image14'])
batches = [[1,2,3,4],[7,8,9,10],[3,4,5,6]]

image_batches = np.array([im_data[batch_idx] for batch_idx in batches])
image_batches
```

**Output:**

```
array([['image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4'],
       ['image7', 'image8', 'image9', 'image10'],
       ['image3', 'image4', 'image5', 'image6']], dtype='<U7')
```

Cheers.